# session timeout configuration in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, session, web-config

I am new to .net and MVC framework of it as well. 
I need to create session timeout functionality. 
So I tried

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

I tried mode="InProc" as well with no luck.
I already has this line in Web.Config

```
<sessionState timeout="30" 
              mode="SQLServer" 
              cookieName="SafeAuto.QuoteAndPurchase" 
              sqlConnectionString="Data Source=CORPSQLTS09RM18;user id=webuser;password=M@r3Bar!" 
              cookieless="false" 
              regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
```

And I know we can not use  2 times. 
So anybody has anything in mind to help me out over here. In addition, after session timeout I want to redirect page to specific page.

Comment: What does *no luck* mean (is that a technical term :P)?  What are you expecting to happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: Most people that mention needing Session timeout are actually talking about a login timeout (forms authentication).  Is that the case here?

Comment: Session timeout is not the same as login timeout